# Multiple Knapsack, weight = profit

Tags: complexity-theory, knapsack-problem

I have a research on Knapsack Problems. Now I stopped on special type of a Multiple Knapsack Problem, where weight of each item is equal with profit of this item.

I can't find any paper saying anything about the complexity of this problem. Is it NP-complete or not?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you have multiple separate bins and multiple weights, and the goal is to pack as much weight into the bins as possible without exceeding the per-bin total?

Comment: @templatetypedef yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a problem that can be reduced to mine - The Multiple Subset Sum Problem. The Multiple Subset Sum Problem (MSSP) is the selection of items from a given ground set and their packing into a given number of identical bins such that the sum of the item weights in every bin does not exceed the bin capacity and the total sum of the weights of the items packed is as large as possible. It can be easily reduced to my problem. It proves that my problem is NP-hard.

Comment: Any suggestion where bins are not identical? I have different subsets for different bins; but when I use one item for 1st bin, I cant use it for Second Bin.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-hard via a reduction from the set partition problem. In that problem, you're given a set of integers and are asked whether it's possible to split that set into two sets with the same sum. You can reduce it to your problem as follows: if the set has sum 2k, create two knapsacks of capacity k each and create one item for each number in the set to split. Then, any way of perfectly filling the knapsacks corresponds to a partition of the original set and vice-versa. (If the sum of the numbers isn't even, just map the problem instance to an unsolvable instance of your knapsack problem).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I already found another one problem that can be reduced to mine - The Multiple Subset Sum Problem. The Multiple Subset Sum Problem (MSSP) is the selection of items from a given ground set and their packing into a given number of identical bins such that the sum of the item weights in every bin does not exceed the bin capacity and the total sum of the weights of the items packed is as large as possible. It can be easily reduced to my problem. It also proves that my problem is NP-hard.